# Cannot read property 'manifest' of undefined Error in Ionic

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I am trying to login Facebook with Firebase.  I have installed all the libraries required and completed the required configuration.  Still, whenever I try to start my app it is giving me this error:

```
(node:11160) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read 
property 'manifest' of undefined

at removeOldOptions (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\firebaseapp\plugins\cordova- universal-links-plugin\hooks\lib\android\manifestWriter.js:48:32)ished in 37.33 s
at Object.writePreferences 

(C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\firebaseapp\plugins\cordova-universal-links- 
 plugin\hooks\lib\android\manifestWriter.js:27:19)
at activateUniversalLinksInAndroid 

(C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\firebaseapp\plugins\cordova-universal-links-plugin\hooks\afterPrepareHook.js:65:25)
at C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\firebaseapp\plugins\cordova-universal-links-plugin\hooks\afterPrepareHook.js:45:11
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at run (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\firebaseapp\plugins\cordova-universal-links-plugin\hooks\afterPrepareHook.js:41:17)
at module.exports (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\firebaseapp\plugins\cordova-universal-links-plugin\hooks\afterPrepareHook.js:18:3)
at runScriptViaModuleLoader (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\hooks\HooksRunner.js:188:18)
at runScript (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\hooks\HooksRunner.js:164:16)
(node:11160) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

Comment: did you found the solution ?

Comment: @Santosh In my case i had downgrade mobx version which was creating issues.

Answer (score 34):

**Able to solve this with below changes :**

*Just go to the below file in Ionic*

plugins/cordova-universal-links-plugin/hooks/lib/android/manifestWriter.js

**I fixed issue by changing pathToManifest as below:**

```
var pathToManifest = path.join(cordovaContext.opts.projectRoot, 'platforms', 'android', 'cordovaLib', 'AndroidManifest.xml');
```

to

> var pathToManifest = path.join(
>       cordovaContext.opts.projectRoot, 
>       'platforms', 
>       'android', 
>       'app', 
>       'src', 
>       'main', 
>       'AndroidManifest.xml');

Comment: Thanks, I just used your fix in a React JS + Cordova app, works too !

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my issue with cordova 9.

Comment: Thanks this fixed my issue in Sep 2021. I am alive!!!!!

Answer (score 8):

For anyone that's looking into this these days, the actual fix for this was published by someone which you can pull in as a cordova plugin https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin/issues/133#issuecomment-369260863

> @okaufmann you can use the changed version of the plugin. since it's not merged in the nordnet repository, you must remove the plugin and install again using:
> cordova plugin add https://github.com/walteram/cordova-universal-links-plugin

After doing...

```sh
cordova plugin rm cordova-universal-links-plugin
cordova plugin add https://github.com/walteram/cordova-universal-links-plugin
```

.. my project was able to build successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the AndroidManifest path in the plugin, which seems to be outdated. Check out this:

https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin/issues/146